# Flatten git history but keep commits from HEAD

Tags: git

Using `git rebase --root -i` and switching all the commits but the first one to squash would allow me to flatten the git history.

The problem is this gives me a series of rebase conflicts through more than 3.5k commits. This would be a long and strenuous process when all I really want is to use the committed lines as seen on HEAD, i.e via `git blame` and make them part of a new commit erasing the past git history.

Is there are way to achieve this without rebasing every single commits since the initialized of the repository?

Comment: To better understand your question, what would be the problem with a new repo starting from the actual codebase? Loss of blame info on last changes? Something else?

Comment: @RomainValeri Less blame but yes the data about who has been contributing to the repository in the latest commits that made it into HEAD. Otherwise, resetting the repository would be a feasibly option.